# How to simulate DELETE keystroke inside a string?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, sybase

I using a framework, that creates temporary tables (sqlalchemy and pandas).

However, it creates a table surrounded by quotes, and in my case, I'm using Sybase and it returns an permission error.

When I create manually, without quotes works perfectly.

To workround it, I put \b at the beggining of string:

```
table_name=f'\b{table_name}'
```

When I test with \b, it erases the left quote, but I can't find a way to delete the closing quote.

Obs: I already tested table_name=f'\b{table_name}' + \u'\u007f'

For example:

```
table_name="#test"
df.to_sql(con=engine,name=table_name,index=False)
```

Generates following create:

```
CREATE TABLE "#test" (nome TEXT NULL)
```

I'm getting error, because quotes.

However, with this code, I can remove left quote:

```
table_name="\b#test"
df.to_sql(con=engine,name=table_name,index=False)
```

It generates:

```
CREATE TABLE #test" (nome TEXT NULL)
```

Thanks

Comment: If you have the table string, why not just do `table_name[1:-1]` ? That removes the first and last character from the string (assuming its >1 character long)

Comment: `\b` will make the left quote _appear_ to be deleted when it's rendered to a terminal. That doesn't mean it's _actually gone_; the quote _and_ the backspace are both there in your data, and presumably your database server will be asked to create a table with both characters in its name.

Comment: My problem is with pandas function to_sql, because when I pass the table name as parameter, it automatically adds quotes surround table name

Comment: please update the question with the complete error message(s) you're receiving; it's not clear (to me) if you're running into a 'permission error' or syntax error (ie, existence of the double quotes)

Comment: also, which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the string itself, you can always slice it to remove whatever characters you want. To remove the first and last ones:

```py
>>> table_name = '"some test table"'
>>> table_name[1:-1]  # No surrounding " characters.
some test table
```

Adding delete characters to the string (what you currently have) just affects the console output. Those characters are still present.

Comment: My problem is with pandas function to_sql, because when I pass the table name as parameter, it automatically adds quotes surround table name

Comment: Would you mind adding that info to your post? I'll take a look

Comment: I have edited my post to give more details

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is Sybase ASE and the error the OP is receiving is related to a syntax issue with the use of quotes, consider:

- using double quotes around (table/column) names is referred to (in ASE) as quoted identifiers
- ASE's default behavior is for quoted identifiers to be `off` (ie, generate an error if double quotes are used around (table/column) names)
- in order to use quoted identifiers the client application needs to explicitly enable quoted identifiers either via a connection parameter or via the explicit command `set quoted_identifier on`
- ASE also supports the use of square brackets (`[]`) around (table/column) names with the added benefit that there is no need to explicitly `set quoted_identifier on`

Again, assuming this is Sybase ASE, I'd want to find out if the client side app a) has the ability to use square brackets (`[]`) in place of double quotes or b) has the ability to enable `quoted_identifier` support or c) has the ability to disable quoted identifiers (ie, **not** wrap names in double quotes).

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is with pandas function to_sql, because when I pass the table name as parameter, it automatically adds quotes surround table name

You appear to be using the internal SQLAlchemy dialect for Sybase which is in the process of being replaced by the [external SAP ASE (Sybase) dialect](https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlalchemy-sybase) that I maintain. The issue with DDL rendering of #temp tables was fixed in [version 1.0.1](https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlalchemy-sybase/releases/tag/1.0.1).